# How can I control phone screen rotation via code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to set on each scene of a project different Screen Orientation for the phone.

In the first scene i want it to be only Portrait.
And in other scene to be only LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight.

How can I control it via script?

In unity3d site they put example as :

```
void Start()
{
     Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
}
```

But it's not working, and this way you can give only one possible orientation in each scene. it couldn't be LandscapeLeft and Portrait int the same time.

Comment: Check devices, that you don't have rotation blocked in settings and also check with other applications

Comment: ` Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation ` Check  is  Auto Rotation working?

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the orientation you want in the `start` method for each scene by using :

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
```

I do it exactly like this in my game and it works for IOS and Android devices.
try using **Landscape** and **NOT LandscapeLaft**.
hope it works, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You do that in Build Settings. Under Player settings , you can set the orientation to portrait, Landscape, Auto rotate. On many Android devices, auto rotation is disabled. Toggle on device settings for auto rotate.

Comment: but like this i can only declare for whole game how it will be .. and i want in each sence something else.

Comment: That might be a bit complicated. Not sure you can override the build settings in scene. Anyhow try toggling the device's auto rotate settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I want to use portrait mode only in a certain scene and the rest of the time, to use the other settings I set up in the "Player Settings" (for my case I have landscape left and right).

(Landscape mentioned above is "Obsolete" now).

To fix this, make sure that in the settings you have set up the allowed orientations for auto rotations.

Then in code, use:

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

for the case where you want to use portrait mode.

Then, to go back to the default, use:

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation;
```